# ASP.net 3.5 Webservice returns large dataset

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, web-services

I know there are lots of similar questions out there like this, but all of the solutions are eithers ones I cannot use or do not work. The basics of the issue is that I have to make a web service call that returns a typed dataset. This dataset can have 30,000 rows or more in some cases. So my issue is how do I get the page to be more responsive and perhaps load everything while the web service is still downloading the dataset?

Please note that normally I would never return this amount of data and would instead do paging on the server side, but the requirements for this really lock down what I can do. I can make the web service return JSon if need be, but my problem at that point is how to get the JSON data back into a format that the gridview could use to bind the data. I know there is an external library out there, but that is out as well.

Sad to say that the restrictions I have here are pretty obscene, but they are what they are and I cannot really change them.

TIA
-Stanley

Comment: Have you considered using AJAX to call the web service and update the page afterward ?

Comment: Is the front-end a WinForms or WebForms (or some other)?  It makes a different for the recommended solution.

Comment: Not clear. You must return 30,000 rows in ASP.NET and cannot page?  How is returning JSON from the web service going to help?

Comment: @Blam that is my problem. I am not sure what direction to go and every direction I turn seems to be the same issue. 30k records is just to much, but the request still remains the same. I have to figure out a way to get this to work where the user does not think the page has frozen and just showing a spinning GIF is not a real solution. If I could find a way to load the rest of the page and let the grid load async that would be great. But since I cannot figure out how to make jquery take in a couple of datatsets that are passed to the WS, I havn't been able to figure out how to make this work.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is not an application that I have built from scratch, it is instead an application that run fine, with the exception of speed. I have been tasked with making it run faster and told that if it is not broke do not fix it. Even if it is bad code unless it makes it go faster. I am really kind of tied down on what I can do here so I am trying to find something new on this one. Normally I would have re-written the WS to do paging and sorting on the server so that we only come back with the results that show on the page.

Comment: Update the question not commments.   Still not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common approach to this kind of scenario is to page (in chunks) your data as it comes back.  Do this asynchronously (separate thread).  You might even be able to do this in only two chunks: first 1000 rows, then the rest.  It will seem very responsive to your users.  If there is any way to require the users to filter the result-set, to reduce the result-set, that would be ideal.

@Lostdreamer is right.  Use JQuery to do two AJAX calls. The first call gets the first 1000 rows then kicks off the second call (etc).  Honestly, this is simply simulating what HTTP typically does (limiting packet sizes and loading multiple chunks).